# css selector for first child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's say my html looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <... some html here ...>
</div>
```

I want to get the first direct child of `.container`.

I could do `.container > div:first-child` but that's assuming the it is a `div` which is not always the case.

Comment: `.container > :first-child` without the `div` portion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `:first-child` pseudo-class without a tagname:

```
.container > :first-child
```

This will grab any element that is the immediate first child, regardless of its tagname. This is similar to the way in which we use other pseudo-classes such as `:hover` which alone targets any element, while `a:hover` targets only the hover state of anchors.

Comment: Could I ask a simple add-on question to your answer? Using your code in a Fiddle, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/xkX95/1/), I don't see any CSS reflected. But, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xkX95/2/) (note the omitted **>**), I do. Sorry to tag along, I'm just curious.

Comment: `:first-child` doesn't target textNodes. You need to have an element within the container http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/xkX95/5/

Answer (score 0):

Not using the element itself, but a class is a better solution and way more **semantic for so many reasons**.

And give the class to the children of the element, not only the container like this:

HTML:

```
<article class="container">
  <p class="blah">First paragraph...</p>
  <p class="blah">Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <p class="blah">Dolor sit amet...</p>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
.blah {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

.blah:first-child {
    background: #000;
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Roobyx/ygP4B/

Comment: _(Jonathan Sampson's answer wont work..)_  Are you sure? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xkX95/8/)

Comment: Really not much of a reason to give it a class when you can just target it like so, `.container p { }`. http://jsfiddle.net/ygP4B/1/

Comment: @JoshPowell Mentioning class always is a better suggestion.. unless if you can't change the HTML. In my opinion, this is a good suggestion.

Comment: @Mr_Green I would normally agree with you as well. In this case you are adding more to the html that isn't necessary needed. Is his option good, heck yeah it is but when you are using a setup like that, I personally, find it more efficient to target them with a general selector. He can also use the selector like so, `.container > p { }` to only select the direct descendants of the parent.